# How to know the Extjs fieldset is collapsed or expanded

Tags: java, javascript, user-interface, web-applications, extjs4

In Extjs how I can identify that my fieldset component in expand state or in collapsed state. I have not seen any direct method in extjs documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer, Instead of a method I used 'collapsed' property of field set to know is it collapsed or not.